# Broadcast comparison on sliced numpy array using "," is a lot slower than "]["

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm not sure why comparing on a sliced numpy array using `,` is a lot slower than `][`. For example:

```py
start = time.time()
a = np.zeros((100,100))
for _ in range(1000000):
    a[1:99][1:99] == 1
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
a = np.zeros((100,100))
for _ in range(1000000):
    a[1:99, 1:99] == 1
print(time.time() - start)
```

```py
3.2756259441375732
11.044903039932251
```

That's over 3 times worse.
The time measurements are approximately the same using `timeit`.

I'm working on a recursive algorithm (I intended to do so), and those problems make my program run a lot slower, from about 1 second increased to 10 seconds. I just want to know the reason behind them. May be this is a bug. I'm using Python 3.9.9. Thanks.

Comment: @mozway. OP is clearly aware of that and it's not a typo

Comment: It is not a *lot* faster...

Comment: My bad I misread, I thought the comparison was between block1 and block2 due to the "lot faster", which it isn't

Comment: Consider using timeit for your timings.

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward that is significant enough for me, since I recursively run them really really many times. Millions to billions of times. And have a lot of test cases. Increasing the running time by 10 times will take my whole day or more.

Comment: @MadPhysicist as I said, the result is comparatively the same. You can try it yourself if you want to.

Comment: What if you do the comparison, without `any`?

Comment: What if you assign to a bigger slice?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but recursive algorithms are generally expensive. Are you sure you can't optimize by using a non-recursive approach?

Comment: The second one makes sense: calling `__getitem__(...).__setitem__(...)` is slower than just `__getitem__(...)`. Since assignment is really fast in that case, you're able to see the overhead discrepancy. Assigning to a bigger slice may hide that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's a good question. `,` is still slower than `][` for about 25%. So now I found out that `any` is not the problem. The problem is about the slicing.

Comment: @mozway I intended to do so, since I need to compare algorithms. The others work fine.

Comment: @MadPhysicist as the array becomes bigger, the differences are larger. For both assigning and comparing.

Comment: @NhậtMinh. Thanks. That's fascinating. I'll try to do some digging

Comment: @MadPhysicist cool, thanks for your attention. I'm not in a hurry, so take your time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist uh oh, my mistake here. As the array becomes bigger, the differences are larger for comparisons. And in reverse, for assignments, the differences will become smaller.

Comment: @NhậtMinh. The second one is as expected, so I'll go ahead and say I understand what's going on there. The first one is still a mystery

Comment: Here's another fun one: try removing the `== 1` and just doing `__getitem__` once or twice

Comment: There's something very different in the equals operator. I wonder if it's checking for `base` being the same or something. At least we have a lead

Comment: It begins to converge around n=10000. I haven't checked the 1D case. I wonder if it's related to that somehow

Comment: @MadPhysicist, my testing shows the difference is in the `==1` test, not the slicing.  It comes down to whether the slice is contiguous or not - a slice of rows or a slice of columns.

Comment: @hpaulj. That makes sense

Comment: @NhậtMinh. The difference is because the slices are completely different shapes and memory layouts. Can't believe I missed that

Comment: @MadPhysicist it's completely my fault. You helped me a lot by explaining the broadcast assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is the same as `a[2:99]==1`.  A (98,100) slice followed by a (97,100), and then the == test.

```
In [177]: timeit (a[1:99][1:99]==1)
8.51 µs ± 16.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [178]: timeit (a[1:99][1:99])
383 ns ± 5.73 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [179]: timeit (a[1:99])
208 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The bulk of the time is the test, not the slicing.

```
In [180]: a[1:99,1:99].shape
Out[180]: (98, 98)
In [181]: timeit a[1:99,1:99]==1
32.2 µs ± 12.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [182]: timeit a[1:99,1:99]
301 ns ± 3.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Again the slicing is a minor part of the timing, but the `==` test is significantly slower.  In the first case we selected a subset of the rows, so the test is on a contiguous block of the data-buffer.  In the second we select a subset of rows and columns.  Iteration through the data-buffer is more complicated.

We can simplify the comparison by testing a slice of columns versus a slice of rows:

```
In [183]: timeit a[:,2:99]==1
32.3 µs ± 13.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [184]: timeit a[2:99,:]==1
8.58 µs ± 10.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

As a further test, make a new array with 'F' order.  Now "rows" are the slow slice

```
In [189]: b = np.array(a, order='F')
In [190]: timeit b[:,2:99]==1
8.83 µs ± 20.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [191]: timeit b[2:99,:]==1
32.8 µs ± 31.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

===

But why are you trying to compare these two slices, one that makes a (97,100) array, and the other a (98,98).  They are picking different parts of `a`.

I wonder if  you really meant to test a sequential row, column slice, not two row slices.

```
In [193]: timeit (a[1:99][:,1:99]==1)
32.6 µs ± 92.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comparing just the slicing we see that the sequential one is slower - by just a bit.

```
In [194]: timeit (a[1:99][:,1:99])
472 ns ± 3.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [195]: timeit (a[1:99,1:99])
306 ns ± 3.19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

===

The data for `a` is actually stored in 1d `c` array.  The numpy code uses strides and shape to iterate through it when doing something like `a[...] == 1`.

So imagine (3,6) data buffer looking like

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

sliced with `[1:3]`, it will use

```
[_ _ _ _ _ _ 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

slice with `[:,1:4]` it will use

```
[_ 1 2 3 _ _ _ 1 2 3 _ _ _ 1 2 3 _ _]
```

Regardless of the processor caching details, the iteration through the 2nd is more complex.

Comment: I totally misread the slice in the original question. When you said rows vs columns it became obvious

Comment: Thanks for your help. I completely understood. it. And yep, that's my error. I'll keep the question here in case someone else makes the same mistake as me.

Comment: Beside my fault, the thing about sequential array really interests me. That's why I need to focus in the data structure classes, lol

Comment: @NhậtMinh, That's more of a processor architecture thing. Normally, modern processors don't just read the location you ask from RAM, but a whole chunk around it. If your array is contiguous, you end up being able to process the entire cache without having to load it frequently. When you have to skip elements (e.g. to move across rows), the new memory location will not have been cached, so it requires another load, which takes more time. This is a very informal explanation, but it gets the general idea across. There are actually usually multiple cores and cache levels.

Comment: I added a few lines to show how slicing some columns results in a more complex iteration pattern.  Most of us don't need to know exactly why that iteration takes more time - a lot is going on behind the scenes, `numpy` iteration mechanism, the compiler optimizations, the OS and processor's memory handling etc.  It may also be a moving target, depending on the versions of the various packages and your own computer and its memory.